# Can't find a decent git gui for windows. Anyone know of one?

Tags: windows, linux, git, user-interface, editor

I'm running win7 and need a good git client with a GUI. I like bash but it feels clunky in windows. the GUI that comes with the windows package at git's website is missing a lot of stuff too. I'm considering switching to Ubuntu and using Gedit + git instead. What should I do? stay in windows and use Aptana or Komodo with another git client, or switch to Debian/Ubuntu and use the tools there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) came out recently. It manages local repos as well as supports pushing to github.com. I have been playing with it and must say it is fantastic.

Answer (score 7):

You can find all the exisiting Git FrontEnd GUI in [this page](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#GraphicalInterfaces).

[MSysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) just released a ["Cheetah" edition](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/wiki/GitCheetah), which should be on par with a TorToiseSVN.
Waiting for Cheetah full integration, [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) is already available

[image: TortoiseGit Context menu]

The [Eclipse Egit plugin](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/EclipsePlugin) also makes progress. (see [its wiki](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/))

[image: Egit]

---

For all those tools, I manage just fine with Git on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

You can use gitextensions with Visual Studio. Otherwise I believe you're going to need to get acquianted with the command line.

http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Git Extensions isn't just a Visual Studio plugin. It also comes with a standalone GUI and a shell extension.

Answer (score 2):

You should also take a look at

- [QGit](http://digilander.libero.it/mcostalba/) (there is also a windows downoad)
- [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) (This is a port of TortoiseSvn

Answer (score 1):

[SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) is quite good although not fully featured yet. The only thing puting me off it is the lack of "blame". But it looks like they're aiming for full functionality so they'll certainly implement it in the future.

Comment: +! for Smartgit. Maybe lacking some functions but certainly worth a look.

Comment: SmartGit is a Java app, FYI - just in case that matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

A client that I use regularly is [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/).

Answer (score 0):

[SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (from Atlassian, which runs BitBucket) was recently released for Windows.  I find it suits our needs well.  [Here's a short review](http://www.hitthebits.com/2013/03/sourcetree-for-windows.html).