# Which is official GUI of Git for windows?

Tags: git, version-control

Which is the official GUI of Git for windows?  I'm confused between [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/) and [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/).

I know there is one [GUI from github](http://windows.github.com/) too but I want to use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/account/signup/) for private free hosting too and I think Official github gui of windows will not work with bitbucket. So I want to learn use of common GUI which I can use with any host.

Are there other options? Which one should I choose?

Comment: GitHub's Windows Git client works with Bitbucket repositories (and anonymous git repositories too!).

Comment: The general answer would be: download them, work with them, see which one you like.

Comment: @Shahbaz I did that. Both are exactly same.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22310007/405017 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3672272/405017 and http://superuser.com/q/742536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused between git-scm and msysgit.

[git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/) is the official website for Git. [Msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/) is the project working on (official) Windows binaries of Git, which are called *“Git for Windows”*. So when you are on Windows you use Git for Windows.

Note that Git is not a GUI, it is a set of command line scripts. It does come however with an “official” GUI, [*git-gui*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui). Other than that, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091064/cant-find-a-decent-git-gui-for-windows-anyone-know-of-one) for some more information on Windows GUIs.